# Struct manipulation needs some explanation

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following piece of code:

```
//length, width, height
typedef struct {
float L, W, H;
} TDim;

//contains details for each geometrical form
typedef struct {
char *id; // each geometrical form has a unique id
float volume;
TDim *dim;
} TForm;

TForm* FormAlloc()
{
TForm *F = (TForm*) malloc(MAX * sizeof(TForm));
F->id = (char*) malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
F->dim = (TDim*) malloc(MAX * sizeof(TDim));

return F;
}
```

which is a good exercise of manipulating variables and pointers within more structures.

What I want to do, is to store the id (basically the letter 'F' followed by 1,2,3...), length, width and height of some rectangular cuboid in order to compute its volume.

I need some explanation around the usage of `->` vs `.`
I understand that `->` *works* with addresses and `.` with members.

In `int main()`, I have:

```
F[0].id = "F1"; //the first cuboid has the id "F1"
F[0].dim[0].L = 1; //the first cuboid has length = 11
//could have used F[0].dim->L = 1; as well?
F[0].dim[0].W = 2;
F[0].dim[0].H = 3;

F[1].id = "F2"; //the second cuboid has the id "F2"
F[1].dim[1].L = 4; //this is where it breaks down - SEG_FAULT (I've used gdb to catch it)
```

What causes the SEG_FAULT in that line?

Comment: MAX is defined as the maximum number of cuboids I want to store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function:

```
TForm* FormAlloc()
{
TForm *F = (TForm*) malloc(MAX * sizeof(TForm));
F->id = (char*) malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
F->dim = (TDim*) malloc(MAX * sizeof(TDim));

return F;
}
```

you create a dynamic array of `MAX` elements of `TForm`, but then you only allocate memory for the `id` and `dim` members of the first, hence the segfault when you try to store memory in the second element.

You'll need something like:

```
TForm* FormAlloc(void)
{
    TForm *F = malloc(MAX * sizeof(TForm));

    if ( !F ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX; ++i ) {
        if ( (F[i].id = malloc(MAX)) == NULL ) {
            perror("couldn't allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ( (F[i].dim = malloc(MAX * sizeof(TDim))) == NULL ) {
            perror("couldn't allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return F;
}
```

Most likely, you don't want to use `MAX` for all three purposes, here, i.e. the chances you need exactly the same number of elements of `TForm` as you need characters in each `id` string is probably low.

Other more minor points:

1. `malloc()` can return `NULL`, and you should check for that.
2. In the code in your question, `F[0].id = "F1";` should be `strcpy(F[0].id, "F1");` or similar, since otherwise you're going to lose your reference to the memory you `malloc()`ed.
3. You don't need to, and really shouldn't, cast the return from `malloc()` in C.
4. `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition, so you can leave it out.

For the question in your comment:

> What about `F[0].dim[0].L = 1;` vs `F[0].dim->L = 1;`?

the two are equivalent, here. Using the subscript operator, `dim[0]`, automatically dereferences `dim` for you, so you'd use the `.` operator to get at the elements (`dim[n]` is equivalent to `*(dim + n)` in C). Without the `[0]`, `dim` is a straight pointer, so you'd use the `->` operator. Obviously the first form is much more convenient when you want to access the other elements in the array. For the others, you'd have to replace `F[0].dim[1].L = 1;` with `(F[0].dim + 1)->L = 1;` or similar, to use the `->` operator, which is unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: Understood, good sir! It worked! Thank you! What about `F[0].dim[0].L = 1;` vs `F[0].dim->L = 1;`?